# How to make jump to line automatically unfold

Tags: folding

When I jump to line (`:76`) I end up on a fold, but it doesn't open.

I can quickly unfold the fold and it gets to the right line, but I want to have the fold unfold automatically to save keystrokes.

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `foldopen` setting controls which commands will open folds. In [`:help 'foldopen'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27foldopen%27) we can see the list of possible values:

```
            item            commands
            all             any
            block           "(", "{", "[[", "[{", etc.
            hor             horizontal movements: "l", "w", "fx", etc.
            insert          any command in Insert mode
            jump            far jumps: "G", "gg", etc.
            mark            jumping to a mark: "'m", CTRL-O, etc.
            percent         "%"
            quickfix        ":cn", ":crew", ":make", etc.
            search          search for a pattern: "/", "n", "*", "gd", etc.
                            (not for a search pattern in a ":" command)
                            Also for [s and ]s.
            tag             jumping to a tag: ":ta", CTRL-T, etc.
            undo            undo or redo: "u" and CTRL-R
```

From reading the documentation you'd expect that `set foldopen+=jump` would do the trick, but it doesn't work for `:76`, only `76G`. I'm not sure if this is intentional or a bug in Vim.

Using `set foldopen=all` *does* work correctly; but may have unwanted side-effects (specifically, you can no longer move "over" a fold with `j` and `k`).

Comment: `:76` is not considered a "jump" in vim and is not remembered in the jumplist (`:jumps`).  `76G` on the other hand is a jump (documented in `:h jump-motions`, so unlikely to be a bug).

You may want to add that you can use `zv` after `:76` to open the fold.

Comment: @Mass The OP doesn't want to have to type anything to open the fold,once they land on it.

Comment: Just like `:76`, jumping while launching vim doesn't seem to open folds (example: `gvim +76 myfile.tex`... I'm using it with the option `--servername` with synctex). Is there a workaround? What's the Ex command for jumping?

Comment: I have tried `gvim --servername GVIM "+normal 76G" myfile.tex` but it doesn't unfold.

Comment: Something that worked for me to open folds from via the server capability:
`gvim --servername VIMTEX --remote '+normal 76GzO<CR>' myfile.tex` (for some reason, the `zO` (open folds) and carriage return are needed.